# XAML can't get text from label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm getting such error

> The name 'ScoreBtn' does not exist in the current context

and

> The name 'LvlBttn' does not exist in the current context

on c# side but I can get text of Label x:Name="Lines". Where is mistake and how can I fix it?

Thanks for any help,

```
 </Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="false">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Hidden" Width="300">Right</Button>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="311" >
        <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" Click="btnPlay_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/>
        <Button x:Name="Score" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="170" Click="buttonPlay_Click"  >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="img1" Source="Images/play.png" Stretch="Fill" />
------------------->>   <Label x:Name="ScoreBtn" FontFamily="Bradley Hand ITC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.8" Content="Score"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="level" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="170" Click="buttonPlay_Click"  >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="img1" Source="Images/play.png" Stretch="Fill" />
------------------->>   <Label Content="Level 1" x:Name="LvlBttn" FontFamily="Bradley Hand ITC" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.8"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Label Visibility="Hidden" Content="Lines " Height="56" x:Name="Lines" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Right, it's in a template. This is going to be a bit of a pain. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: So I can't get/set text from c#?

Comment: In your code, you'll need to dig through the Button's visual children, and their visual children. Doable, but a bit of a hassle. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Actually It doesn't matter how it will be done, it can be really awful solution. I need to change text dynamically in this label

Comment: _"I need to change text dynamically in this label"_ -- the answer to that is pretty much always: set your view model up correctly and change the text there. Bind the view model to the label, so that the label is automatically changed when the view model value changes. This is WPF 101. If you've tried that approach and failed, you need to be more specific: include a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with. Accessing the element in code-behind is almost always the wrong thing to do, even if you weren't dealing with a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the `Label` for the button named `Score`. `"ScoreBtn"`is the name of the label element. It's not as complicated as I thought it would be.

```
var label = (Label)Score.Template.FindName("ScoreBtn", Score);
```

You really ought to listen to Peter Duniho, write a viewmodel, and bind the label's `Content` property to a viewmodel property, but if you don't already have a viewmodel, you may not want to rewrite your entire project. Since you don't have a single `Binding` in your XAML, I imagine that might be the case.

Comment: Yes I know that it's ugly solution and it shouldn't be like that but I've just need it for one simple application which have to be done really fast :-) so it was perfect for me. Thanks guys